# Tag merge: [web] → [web-development]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

We have two general "web" tags<sup>1</sup> in the context of software development:

- [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) (680 questions)
- [web](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) (104 questions)

Is there any reason why these can't be merged? Are there specific examples of [web](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) questions that aren't [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) questions and can't be tagged with anything else?

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: I know there are a number of more specialized tags, like [web-applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications), [web-framework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-framework), and [web-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-design), but this is specifically about the general topic of web software development, not subsets of that topic.

Answer (score 2):

Open [web](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) questions that are not about [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development):

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91143/ms-certifications-for-non-it-students
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105264/trying-to-evaluate-answers-provided-by-an-online-technology-school
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80303/is-there-a-beta-testing-community
- [Online Advertising And Marketing Your Services?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94397/online-advertising-and-marketing-your-services)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45228/do-microsofts-desktop-platforms-have-as-much-potential-as-web-platforms
- [Overcoming general lack of UI design skill in developers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110675/overcoming-general-lack-of-ui-design-skill-in-developers)
- [I need a true random number generator web service](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76822/i-need-a-true-random-number-generator-web-service)
- [Evaluating Software Maintenance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125545/evaluating-software-maintenance)

As a first step I retagged all [web]+[development], [web]+[applications], [web]+[app] questions. Eight of them in total, so I spammed the frontpage a bit. If the questions I've listed above are appropriately retagged or closed or are deemed [web-development] questions, I'd say it's safe to merge.

[web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) and all related tags would be my first proposal for a structured cleanup anyway, so merging the tags would make my life a bit easier when the time comes.

Comment: Thanks for going through them: I agree that those aren't really about web-development, but are any of them specifically about the web though? Seems like we could just remove the tag and let [web] die.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Already retagged 8 questions, didn't want to spam frontpage any more today. Some of the questions on the list I consider off topic, and I thought others would notice as well and close them without spamming the frontpage and others have weird tags and I don't know what tags would be appropriate.[web] won't die soon, there are 26 closed questions, a "don't use this tag" wiki summary would be nice, even if no one bothers to read those... I wouldn't mind if we killed [web] asap, but that's just me...

Comment: @MarkTrapp I did another round of retagging, and removed [web] from all of the questions in the list. So as far as I'm concerned, you can go ahead and merge with [web-development].